# Why do we need midas.dll in Delphi projects?

Tags: delphi, dll

I have noticed that in many Delphi projects there is a file which is `midas.dll`. I tried surfing the internet to find what it does but I failed. Can anybody explain to me why do we need `midas.dll`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Client datasets are specialized datasets that hold all their data in memory. The support for manipulating the data they store in memory is provided by midaslib.dcu or midas.dll. The format that client datasets use for storing data is self-contained and easily transported, which allows client datasets to...[read the rest here.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_Client_Datasets_-_Overview)

Comment: Is `midas` some kind of abbreviation? What does the word stand for? Just wondering.

Comment: Herodotus said that a "**Midas** son of Gordias" made an offering to the Oracle of **Delphi** : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midas

Comment: Some ancient info on it in an EDN article: https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20870  very out of date on licensing information but shows what it was used for. Also: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27860